# Swift CollectionViewCell showing Subview, which is NOT added

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `collectionView`, which returns 20 cells. The cells get their information from an API. If `dates == true`, the `calendarImageView` and the `eventDatesLabel` should be added/shown, else it shouldn't. The testprint is showing for the cells with `dates==true` and not showing for cells with `dates==false`. The cells are pretty big, so you only see two cells on iPhone 7 and to see the other cells, you have to scroll down. If a cell with `dates==false` is within the first cells, the `calendarImageView` and `eventDatesLabel` is not showing (as it should), but if a cell with `dates==false` is further down, it still gets displayed (while it shouldn't), even if the testprint is not showing, which would mean, that the views are not even added to the cell. How is this possible? Also the `bannerView` works the same. But there I have no problem at all, even if it is written exactly the same.

```
class HomeCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    func configure(with homeEvent: HomeEvent) {
        //configures the content of subviews with variables from homeEvent, which is the result of api request
        setupViews()
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        //resets the variables for reuse
    }
    
    //here I defined all the labels, imageViews and so on...
    
    weak var homeControllerDelegate: HomeControllerDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(eventImageView)
        addSubview(genreLabel)
        if discount == 1 {
            addSubview(fixDiscountLabel)
        }
        else {
            addSubview(variableDiscountLabel)
        }
        addSubview(eventTitleLabel)
        addSubview(eventSubTitleLabel)
        if dates == true {
            print("test")
            addSubview(calendarImageView)
            addSubview(eventDatesLabel)
        }
        if banner == true {
            addSubview(bannerView)
            bannerView.addSubview(bannerLabelNormal)
            bannerView.addSubview(bannerLabelBold)
        }
        
        //here i set the constraints

        }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = eventCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: homeCellId, for: indexPath) as? HomeCell
            else {
                return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        let event = homeEvents[indexPath.item] //homeEvents is an Array of Data for each cell. So every Element in this Array contains the variables needed to set the cells content, like dates, banner, ...
        cell.configure(with: event)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 233/255, green: 233/255, blue: 233/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        cell.homeControllerDelegate = self
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also remove subviews based on whether they are in the view hierarchy, based on the data. As others have said, the collection view cells are reused. If at index 0 you had a cell where dates was true, and you added the calendarImageView and eventDatesLabel, then when that cell is offscreen it will be reused at another index, let's say index 10. So when it is being reused at index 10 the views you added before will still be there and you have to manage them. So you might be able to solve it by doing the following:

```
func setupViews() {
    addSubview(eventImageView)
    addSubview(genreLabel)
    if discount == 1 {
        addSubview(fixDiscountLabel)
    }
    else {
        addSubview(variableDiscountLabel)
    }
    addSubview(eventTitleLabel)
    addSubview(eventSubTitleLabel)
    if dates == true {
        print("test")
        addSubview(calendarImageView)
        addSubview(eventDatesLabel)
    } else {
        if subviews.contains(calendarImageView) {
            calendarImageView.removeFromSupeview()
        }

        if subviews.contains(eventDatesLabel) {
            eventDatesLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    if banner == true {
        addSubview(bannerView)
        bannerView.addSubview(bannerLabelNormal)
        bannerView.addSubview(bannerLabelBold)
    } else {
        if subviews.contains(bannerView) {
            bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

But honestly this code is a bit messy, there is too much logic for something that can be simplified with separation. I would personally suggest making two different cells (one that has your calendar views and one that has your banner views), register both of them to your collection view, and then based on your object dequeue the one that you actually need. In that way each cell will just have one set layout, and you don't have to manage cells as they are reused.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Makes complete sense to me. Now I finaly understood, how reusing works exactly. I will try your solution, but I think it would be more work to make multiple cells, because there is more that just the calendaricon and the banner. I just used these two, so there is no unimportant information.

Comment: But what confuses me is, that I have no problems with the banner. It works as it should

Comment: Maybe right now it is more work to make multiple cells, but in the long term let's say you have a new feature you want to add only if the banner is true, then there is more confusing logic to add in this setupViews function. But of course it's fine to stick with this for now if it is working and you are satisfied, I was just giving suggestions on what is the better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Problem might be caused by the fact that the cell is reusable, so try removing all the subviews in `prepareForReuse()` method.

Comment: When I remove the subviews from prepareForReuse(), the dates variable is not correct anymore. So for a cell, where it should be false, it is true then

Comment: In configure method which is called in cellForItemAt method. I will edit the post and add the code.

Comment: I still cannot see at what point you take value for date from HomeEvent that you. Where is defined variable dates that is used in setUpViews() method and where do you update it?

Comment: In your setupViews function you should not only add Subviews but also either remove them or hide them based on the information

Answer (score 0):

Add all the subviews at once in your setupViews method, then show/hide views for the required condition.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(eventImageView)
    addSubview(genreLabel)
    addSubview(fixDiscountLabel)
    addSubview(variableDiscountLabel)
    addSubview(eventTitleLabel)
    addSubview(eventSubTitleLabel)
    addSubview(calendarImageView)
    addSubview(eventDatesLabel)
    addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerView.addSubview(bannerLabelNormal)
    bannerView.addSubview(bannerLabelBold)
}

private func hideAllViews(){
    eventImageView.isHidden = true
    genreLabel.isHidden = true
    eventTitleLabel.isHidden = true
    eventSubTitleLabel.isHidden = true
    fixDiscountLabel.isHidden = true
    variableDiscountLabel.isHidden = true
    calendarImageView.isHidden = true
    eventDatesLabel.isHidden = true
    bannerView.isHidden = true
}

func setupViews() {
    hideAllViews()
    if discount == 1 {
        fixDiscountLabel.isHidden = false
    }
    else {
        variableDiscountLabel.isHidden = false
    }
    if dates == true {
        print("test")

        calendarImageView.isHidden = false
        eventDatesLabel.isHidden = false

    }
    if banner == true {
        bannerView.isHidden = false
    }

    //here i set the constraints

}
```